# Generalized Cesàro summability of $(-1)^nn^p$

Tags: sequences-and-series, cesaro-summable

A sequence $\{a_n\}_{n\geq 0}$ is said to be $(C,\alpha)$-summable if $\lim_{n\to\infty} S^\alpha_n$ exists, where $$ S^n_\alpha = \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{ {n \choose k}  }{ {n+\alpha \choose k}  } a_k. $$
How could one show $a_k = (-1)^k(2k+1)^2$ is $(C,3)$-summable? In general, is it true that the sequence $a_k = (-1)^k k^p$ is $(C,p+1)$-summable for positive integers $p$?

Comment: If $\alpha$ is an integer, then $\binom{n+\alpha}k=0$ for $k>n+\alpha$, so the given expression is ill-defined. Perhaps you meant to sum over $k\in[0,n]$? And likewise $a_k$ instead of $a_n$.

Comment: Yes. The summation should be up to $n$. Thanks for your reminder.